# How can I cache YouTube videos with Squid Cache?

Tags: squid, cache

we're using the Squid cache in our company. Is there any way we can cache YouTube videos?

cheers :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First hit for "Squid youtube" on a popular search engine: http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/DynamicContent/YouTube

Comment: Has anyone had any success with the method described in this article?

Comment: I did it a year and a half ago, and I had mixed success, essentially with setting the maximum object size... I don't know if youtube changed anything that breaks this config, as I've been months wuthout caching youtube...

Comment: Without caching youtube? do u mean 'months caching YT' ??

Answer (score 0):

The only acceptable (and simple) solution I've found so far is [InComum](http://sourceforge.net/projects/incomum/) Squid2 helper.

It uses `storeurl_rewrite_program` to cache resources from domains wich do load balance (Eg: youtube, avast, etc).