# Caching youtube on LAN

Tags: cache

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I cache YouTube videos with Squid Cache?](https://serverfault.com/questions/9281/how-can-i-cache-youtube-videos-with-squid-cache)

I am an Administrator for a net cafe. We have limited monthly traffic allowance and in past our investigations showed that 100 out of 500 videos are repeated. I am looking for any way to cache youtube videos on our server so users can watch the same video from our servers. I have tried Squid and searched a lot but nothing helped me. If there is something anyone can suggest I will be very thankful, as this had become a headache for us.

Comment: And http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/DynamicContent/YouTube didn't help?

Comment: And also this seems to be a Serverfault-specific question.

Comment: @vtorhonen: It is now - such comments become outdated very quickly ;)

Comment: I have checked this as well but it also didn't helped, anyway other out? It failed because youtube continuously changes the server from their clusters so i Squid can't understands, but one thing the video_id and video remains the same...Anyway other out for this?

Answer (score 2):

http://cachevideos.com/ appears to be what you want.

AFAIK you are not supposed to cache youtube vids, youtube don't like it. I don't understand why.

Comment: Probably because their ranking mechanism relies on views, and possibly completed views, which wouldn't be measurable if the content was served from a local cache.  It probably also simplifies content licensing issues.

Comment: because youtube has to count the views of each video so , if one video is transferred  from cache , it could led problems to youtube regarding their Counting the videos mechanism.

Comment: Hm. I guess that could be it. You'd think there's be ways around that though (count when a cache asks if it has been modified?) Thanks for the suggestions tho.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a nerdy thought, but I felt like sharing it. Nowadays, browsers themselves cache all YouTube videos. Hence, if, by any possibility you're able to maintain your browser cache from being overwritten, say by increasing the memory allocated to your browser's cache or by backing the contents before being overwritten, then you might succeed in you goal.
--------------------------------------------**UPDATE**--------------------------------------------
[here is the link](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2009/06/browsers-cache-youtube-videos.html) to an article that says that browsers are capable of caching youtube videos

Comment: I'm not sure that's true.. Can you provide evidence to back up your claims about browsers caching YT content?  Static assets, yeah, but streamed and flv videos?

Answer (score 0):

Well i have Windows SteadyState installed on all my machines which means, everything sweeps after a restart/logoff, i have emailed Qbik (WinGate makers) regarding their wingate, what if that can cache it! But their must be something else! CacheVideos charges allot and also i have tried it, it misses 4 out of 10 videos! So better to use some more good program, Well i am looking forward...!